# xe:namePicker replace image with fontawesome icon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, xpages-extlib

I am using bootstrap on top of an xpages application. the version of the extension library does not include bootstrap so most controls I have to apply theming for myself.

Now I am running into a namePicker control where I would like to replace the default image with a fontawesome icon, since I use that across the app.

Anyone has done this before?

Comment: should have trusted myself a bit more. this does the job: $( document ).ready(function() {
 $("img[src*='iconNamePicker.png']").replaceWith("<i class='fa fa-address-book-o' aria-hidden='true'></i>"); 
});

Comment: Add it as answer